# How to do categories in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I store the categories that a post belongs to in a database and I'd like to use them in the URL. How can I do this dynamically?

For example, I'd like to generate a URL like example.com/action-adventure/post-name.

I'd imagine it would involve routes.php, but I just don't know how to do it dynamically.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199389/codeigniter-category-subcategory-subsubcategory-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be problematic, consider:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'blog/post/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'blog/post_category/$1/$2';
```

-

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'category/$1';
```

**Blog/post** would have priority here, so naming conventions become an issue/or not

Structure your links before hand I would suggest

```
public function post_category($type, $post_name){}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way (not messing with routes) is to grab the uri segments. Your url will look something like

```
http://example.com/controller/index/category/post
```

And in your php, you can grab the category and post like

```
$category = $this->uri->segment(3);
$post = $this->uri->segment(4);
```