# How to make dynamic url with category name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi please help me regarding URL in codeigniter.

i want url like :  www.mysite.com/category/pageurl

```
    example1 :  www.mysite.com/blog/pageurl
    example2 :  www.mysite.com/services/pageurl
    example2 :  www.mysite.com/about/pageurl
```

mycontroller file

```
function postdata()
{  
    $post['url']= array
    (
        $category = $this->uri->segment(3),
        $posturl = $this->uri->segment(4),
    );
    $this->Post_model->get_slug($category,$posturl);
    $this->load->view('postdata',$post);    
}
```

my model file

```
function get_slug($category,$posturl)
{
    return $this
        ->db
        ->get_where(
            'post', 
            array(
                'post_type'=>$category,
                'post_url' => $posturl
            )
        )->result();
}
```

my routes file code

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Post/postdata/$1/$2';
```

and my view

```
<?php
foreach($url as $post):
?>
    <h1><?php echo $post->post_title;?> </h1>
    <hr>
    <p>
    <?php  echo $post->post_content;?>
    </p>
<?php 
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: whats your problem ?

Comment: how to make dynamic urls with category name in codeigniter

Comment: i dont get it - you post something here which looks @first sight somewhat ok (beside the uri segment thing) - have you no results? do you get any errors or what ? Or is it a question if this code looks fine and you are not sure ? Or like i said: Whats your problem ?

Comment: my url is not working and not show data on page please find where is mistake.

Comment: what do you mean with *is not working* ? Do you get any 404 errors or can you jump into the controller or what ? dude the most important thing here is - you've to describe the kind of error you are facing - if i've to guess here, it could be a long day...

Comment: there is no error in my code

Comment: try to print out an `echo 'test'; ` immediately @the beginning of your postdata function - and take a look if you see the test...

Comment: sir first check my code there is any error in my code ..? and tell me what's is working

Comment: sry i'm done here ...

Comment: i need something like that   
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574743/how-to-do-categories-in-codeigniter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa